# Google Form and Sheets

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I have created a Google Form that is being used daily by multiple people. The data that is being collected goes into google sheets automatically.  Is there a way to set up a formula so that the data that is received daily automatedly hides the rows once the day is over? For example I have 10 rows of data that came in on 10/29.  Tomorrow 10/30 there will be another 10 entries of different information.  I would like the 10/29 data to hide those rows automatically and keep 10/30 date until the next day.. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: You can use another sheet and filter data to see only entries from Same Date. In google-sheets (unlike Excel) there is a Filter() function that needs no calling or scripting, and can filter rows & columns!

Comment: I thought about the filters but I would like to have the date for previous day hidden automatically so I do not need to go in daily to hide them. I have 7 spreadsheets going with 30 rows of info coming in daily.  I have someone looking at this information daily taking  the 30 rows of data and using it for something.  Its such a hard thing to explain.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: Kim, filter() function does exactly that, in a different sheet you can call the entire sheet (in range form) that fills with forms and filter to show data that date(F1:F)>today()-1 for example. This is simple and fast... otherwise you go in google-script (javascript), not worth the pain...

Comment: @KimStar u'd explain it clearly. Well done. | For that "someone looking at this information daily".. he/she just need to apply the filter on another(new) sheet. Don't edit/touch the original sheet where the data is live/incoming. just put `today()`&'filter()' in the new sheet and the result will only display the value that "someone" need. | If you had tried https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop#zippy=%2Csort-by-color%2Csort-an-entire-sheet and still stuck.. you may share sample sheet to experiment.. and ask others to check ur filter equation/setting.

Comment: Here is a sample of what  I am working on.  To paint a big picture this data is coming from a form.  This information is being entered daily.  I have 7 of these forms with 7 different spreadsheets.  ( Which I want to keep each building separate with diff forms.)  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kYeUoO-Jhl8G-IiXbXa2BG5-gUz99LzVgXtP6fLtF4U/edit#gid=0     I am pretty efficent with sheets but for some reason I can't wrap my head around this sort.  Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: 7 Managers using the spread sheets I do not want them touching anything.  I have all 7 spreadsheets locked.  So this has to be an automatic process with the dates.